# Add more details to Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to add more details to a simple event in the google calendar. (extra information to the event)

For example, I would like to add an event with a checkbox for another user in the calendar. (The calendar is being used by 4 users and we like to be coordinated)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Extended Properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties)

> Adding and updating
>
> Extended properties are set on the Events resource, and like other
>   fields can be set in insert, update, and patch requests. Using patch
>   requests is the preferred method, as it allows you to manipulate some
>   properties while leaving others untouched. Adding a new property with
>   the same key will overwrite any existing properties with the same key.
>   The following example shows setting a private property:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
{
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "petsAllowed": "yes"
    }
  }
}
```